# WP_Query $args and compare operators

Tags: sql, wordpress, operators

I'm having troubles to generate an sql query with operators.Actually wirte this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged,  
    'meta_query' => array(
        //CITY
        array(
            'key' => 'city',
            'value' => $city,           
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),    
        //type
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => $type,           
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),    
        //PRICE
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 100, 5000 ),          
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'          
        ),      
    )
);
```

This code work fine, but now, i need to get the posts with `price` between `$start` and `$end`, OR `price = -1`. In other words, post that not have set the price, or set to `-1` must show in the query. The others conditions (city, type,etc) must be match with `AND`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is to add a filter onto posts_where or posts_join to inject a custom SQL condition into the query.

Something along these lines:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key='price' AND 
    (wp_postmeta.meta_value='-1' OR 
    CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS INT) BETWEEN $start AND $end)
```